# Issue while running Djangorestframework api on Ubuntu Server

Tags: django, selenium, django-rest-framework, ubuntu-server, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have developed an api using djangorestframework. It uses selenium and firefox driver. It works completely fine on my localhost. But it gives WebDriverException when I try to run it on server.

Server and host both have the same environment, as mentioned below:

```
Ubuntu - 14.04;
python - 2.7.6;
Django - 1.9.6;
djangorestframework - 3.3.3;
selenium - 2.53.2;
Mozilla firefox - 46.0.1;
bs4 - 0.0.1;
```

[image]

The error message is:

```
WebDriverException
Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it
/home/Ubuntu/local/lib/pyhton2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary in _wait_until_connectable, line 98
```

Comment: do you have firefox installed? maybe enable logging as this message suggest - this does not looks like django issue but your selenium

Comment: it seems you are using edge for access your api

Comment: I used headless browser, PhantomJS, and it solved the problem!